# How can I exit Forth with a non-zero exit status?

Tags: forth, gforth

I would like to exit a Forth program (using Gforth 0.7.3) with a non-zero exit status.

I've tried:

```
1 bye
```

But the 1 is not interpreted as an argument to `bye` (and I didn't expect this to work anyway; I couldn't find any hint in the documentation that `bye` would accept an argument).

Note that I do not want to trigger an exception, as that also prints an error message (unless there is a way to suppress the error message of the exception from within the Forth program itself).

So, how do I exit a Forth program back to the hosted environment/OS providing a non-zero exit status?
(Basically, I'm looking for the equivalent of `return EXIT_FAILURE; // from main()` (C) or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` (C) or `System.exit(1);` (Java).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Gforth, the internal word `(bye) ( n -- )` can be used to return the exit status to the OS.

For example, the following command in Bash:

```
gforth -e '123 (bye)' ; echo $?
```

prints "123".

In general, a method to return a non-zero exit status is not standardized yet.

Comment: Works, that was _exactly_ what I was looking for, lovely, thank you!